# Translation with wordpress what does the process involve?

Tags: translation

What's the process involved with translating content into the language of your own? Or multiple languages?

I'm looking to create a website that requires various different language translations.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/)

Main features:

- qTranslate Services - Professional human and automated machine
  translation with two clicks
- One-Click-Switching between the languages - Change the language as
  easy as switching between Visual and HTML
- Language customizations without changing the .mo files - Use
  Quick-Tags instead for easy localization
- Multilingual dates out of the box - Translates dates and time for you
     Comes with a lot of languages already builtin! - English, German,
  Simplified Chinese and a lot of others
- No more juggling with .mo-files! - qTranslate will download them
  automatically for you
- Choose one of 3 Modes to make your URLs pretty and SEO-friendly. -
  The everywhere compatible ?lang=en, simple and beautiful /en/foo/ or
  nice and neat en.yoursite.com
- One language for each URL - Users and SEO will thank you for not
  mixing multilingual content